# ASP.NET MVC 3 how can I create dynamic attribute name in view in cshtml?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In MVC 3, view-cshtml file, I want to create a dynamic id like below. How can I merge "videoItem_" and "@MenuItemIndex" to get "videoId_5" for example?

```
<div class='videoItem' id='videoItem_@MenuItemIndex'>
```

EDIT : I only need to add();

```
<div class='videoItem' id='videoItem_@(MenuItemIndex)'>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the variable in brackets to make the expression explicit:

```
<div class='videoItem' id='videoItem_@(MenuItemIndex)'>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@for(int i = 0; i < SomeInteger; i++){
    <div class='videoItem' id='videoItem_@(i)'>
}
```